# Update a single external repo in Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I want to update a single external dependency before I do `bazel build`. 
Is there a way to do this?

`bazel sync` refreshes all the external dependencies, I am looking for something to just refresh a single external dependency.

`bazel fetch` does not seem to work for me, at least when I tried fetching a remote git repo.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example from your WORKSPACE / BUILD files? Bazel will refresh only changed dependencies where the others will be used from cache,

Comment: @ShmulikKlein Yep, but when it is an external dependency, how will baze know that the external dependency has changed? Is there some command I can use to invalidate the cache for a single depedency, so that bazel fetches the depedency again?

Comment: Your external dependency should be pinned to its checksum or commit hash, so builds are reproducible. It would be confusing if running a build twice at different times result in different results, caused by a change in an unpinned external dependency.

Comment: @Jin I am currently using a branch for the external dependency. The workflow you are suggesting would mean, each time, I make a change in the other repo, I have to make a hash change in my current repo to be able to fetch the new version.
Is there a better flow? Or is the contract such that bazel will only update a dependency when the checksum changes?

Comment: Yes, Bazel would only re-fetch if the WORKSPACE definition changes. So if the checksum changes, it'll re-run the repository rule (like http_archive). A workaround is to manually delete `$(bazel info output_base)/external/<repo_name>` and `$(bazel info output_base)/execroot/__main__/external/<repo_name>`  every time you want to force Bazel to refetch a single repository, but this reaches into the internals of Bazel and may have breaking changes.

Answer (score 3):

TL,DR

1. delete repo root or marker file in `$(bazel info output_base)/external`
2. `bazel shutdown`
3. `bazel build //target/related/with/the:repo`

---

For later coming, this requirement generally happens when external repo is not properly configured or you are the one that is configuring it and it is broken for now.

E.g. for cuda in tensorflow, a custom `repository_rule` is defined for bazel to **collect** cuda headers installed on the system and form a local external repository `@local_config_cuda`, however, if you updated part of the library, say, upgrade cudnn from 7.3.1 to 7.6.5 , the `repository_rule` will not simply, automatically, intelligently re-execute for you. In this case, there is no way for you to use checksum or specify a list of file (before you **collect** that list for file) as input for the `repository_rule`.

Simply put, there is no way for bazel to force re-execute a single repository_rule at the moment. See [Working with External Dependencies - Layout](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/external.html#layout).

To rebuild the local external repository, see [Design Document: Invalidation of remote repositories](https://bazel.build/designs/2016/10/18/repository-invalidation.html) for how to invalid the local repo.